# Index member of class as list in python

Tags: python, list, oop, metaclass, class-decorator

Assume I have a simple class like

```py
class Foo:
  def __init__(bar):
    self.x = transform1(bar)
    self.y = transform2(bar)
```

I'm now interested in generating a class, where I can pass an iterable for `bar` to the initializer and get back an instance of `Foo` where i can access the members `x` and `y` like iterables of the size of `bar`, i.e.

```py
x = [1, 2, 3]
foo = Foo(x)
plt.plot(foo.x, foo.y)
```

I know one could easily do

```py
foo = [Foo(elem) for elem in x]
plt.plot([elem.x for elem in foo], [elem.y for elem in foo])
```

but this feels verbose and probably is not very efficient. I can roughly imagine a solution with numpy structured arrays, but I'm just curious if there are any standard solutions to this. Perhaps using metaclasses. Googling mostly came up with results for how to get a list of all the members of a class or similar.

If one could even come up with a solution that allows for indexing *either* the object `foo` *or* its members, this would be grand.

Comment: It feels like there's a use for `zip` here. `list(zip(*zip(t1, t2)) == [tuple(t1), tuple(t2)]` for independent iterables.

Comment: edit: I am removing the "metaclass" tag - this is mostly ordinary operations with objects.

Comment: @jsbueno I wouldn't be so quick to judge, I feel especially the last part can only be achieved with metaclasses.

Comment: Ok - I needed a "class decorator" in the end - it is almost the same.- so I am putting it back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get this right, you just want to transform all elements in `bar` at once.
just do it, instead of one scalar at a time. Just do it:

```
class Foo:
  def __init__(bar):
    self.x = [transform1(el) for el in bar] 
    self.y = [transform2(el) for el in bar]
```

It is really that simple. There are fancy things if you'd want to run transform1 and transform2 in parallel, using threads or processes, or if you'd like to have all the transforms calculated just as needed, in a lazy way.

But for plotting your graph, a list will do. And there are even no gains in doing it in a single `for` loop instead of two list comprehensions - the time taken in the iteration using `for` itself is negligible.

---

If you want to be able to index the instance itself, and get back objects that have the needed attributes, what is necessary is to write a class with the `__getitem__` method - and have the objects returned by getitem to have both attributes.

For that you could use a simpler class, representing your scalar, and depending on what you need, this simpler class can be a namedtuple:

```
from collections import namdtuple

ScalarFoo = namedtuple("ScalarFoo", "x y")

class Foo:
  def __init__(bar):
    self.x = [transform1(el) for el in bar] 
    self.y = [transform2(el) for el in bar]
  def __getitem__(self, index):
       return ScalarFoo(self.x[index], self.y[index])
  def __len__(self):
       return len(self.x)
```

(The `__len__` method, combined with the `__getitem__` allows Python to use instances of `Foo` automatically in for-loop iterations)

Now, if you want to get it really interesting, let's suppose your `Foo` class, with the scalar application of the transforms exists as in your question - it is possible to "transform" it so that it can operate with sequences.

Than we get closer to the original `metaclass` research - and can be achieved by using a class decorator. Class decorators were introduced a long while back to replace some of the uses of metaclasses.

```
def autosequence(cls):
    """Transforms the received class into a factory,
    so that if a sequence or iterator is passed as the first
    argument to it, a new, sequence class is used. If the
    resulting class is used in an iteration or as a sequence,
    an instance of the original class is returned
    """
    
    class AutoSequence:
        def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
            self.sequence = list(args[0])
            self.other_args = args[1:]
            self.kw = kw
        
        def __getitem__(self, index):
            return cls(self.sequence[index], *self.other_args, **self.kw)
        
        def __len__(self):
            return len(self.sequence)
        
        def __repr__(self):
            return f"Lazy sequence of f{cls.__name__} objects with {len(self)} elements"
        
        
    def factory(*args, **kw):
        if args and hasattr(args[0], "__len__") or hasattr(args[0], "__iter__"):
            return AutoSequence(*args, **kw)
        return cls(*args, **kw)
        
    factory.__name__ = cls.__name__
    return factory



def transform1(a):
    return a

def transform2(a):
    return a ** 2


@autosequence
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.x = transform1(bar)
        self.y = transform2(bar)
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({self.x}, {self.y})"
```

And here is how this behaves in the interactive interpreter:

```py
In [24]: a = Foo([1,2,3])                                                                            

In [25]: a[2]                                                                                        
Out[25]: Foo(3, 9)

In [26]: Foo(4)                                                                                      
Out[26]: Foo(4, 16)

In [27]: Foo(4).y                                                                                    
Out[27]: 16

In [28]: a[2].y                                                                                      
Out[28]: 9
```

The "factory" function above could be made into a `__new__` and inserted into the decorated class, and then the resulting decorated class would behave as the real class - but specially if you have introspecting code and need the `Foo` class to be real class operating on scalars, you'd better have two separate classes at all - one creating the sequences, the other dealing with scalars.

In that case you could ust strip the  "factory" function, have "autosequence" to return the AutoSequence class itself, and use it like this:

```py
class Foo:
   ...

FooSequence = autosequence(Foo)
```

Comment: okay, fairly straight forward. But do you have an idea wrt. the last request, i.e. being able to index either the object or an attribute?

Comment: It is more clear now, with the comments - I will give it a shoot

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a single loop instead of 2:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.xs = []
        self.ys = []
        for elem in bar:
            self.xs.append(elem.x) 
            self.ys.append(elem.y)
```

You could hide the loop using `map` and `zip`:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.xs, self.ys = zip(*map(lambda e: (e.x, e.y), bar))
```

Comment: upvote for the oneline, though not very pretty / readable. Any idea about the last part of my question?

Comment: the "single loop" approach there will result in no gain at all: any possible overhead of the 2 `for` loops is surpassed by the `.append` call in Python code.

Comment: @Xaser What do you mean by "index into"? Just do `foo.xs[index]`

Comment: @DeepSpace don't recall having used the word "into". I just mean that, like for numpy structured / record arrays, `foo[0].x` will give me the same as `foo.x[0]`. Rather `foo[0]` produces an instance of `Foo` with scalar members.

Comment: @Xaser I don't recall an instance in which numpy will return the same output for `foo[0].x` and `foo.x[0]`. However, you can implement `__getitem__` to make `foo[...]` will return whatever you want it to return

Comment: @DeepSpace if you are curious, check this out: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html#record-arrays